# Why does fragment changes back when switching orientation?

Tags: android, android-fragments, orientation

So basically what has been happening is my LoginFragment is supposed to load the create account fragment when a button is clicked which it does fine but then when the orientation is changed to landscape it loads the landscape of the LoginFragment. If you switch it back to portrait it crashes. Heres the code for loading the createAccountFragment when the Sign Up button is pressed in the LoginFragment. Let me know if you need any other code. Thanks I really appreciate it guys! Note: Would it help if I destroyed the login fragment view or something?

```
/**
 * Load the create account view.
 */
private void createAccount() {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity()
            .getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(
            ((ViewGroup) getView().getParent()).getId(),
            CreateAccountFragment.newInstance());
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

onCreate for LoginFragment

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
    mUserNameEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.username);

    mPasswordEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.password);
    mPasswordEditText
            .setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id,
                        KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                    if (id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                        attemptLogin();
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

    view.findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    attemptLogin();
                }
            });

    view.findViewById(R.id.register_button).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    createAccount();
                }
            });

    view.findViewById(R.id.forgot_button).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    forgotPassword();
                }
            });
    return view;
}

On create for CreateAccountFragment
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_account, container, false);

                mUserNameEditText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
                mEmailEditText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
                mPasswordEditText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
                mConfirmPasswordEditText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.etPasswordConfirm);

                mCreateAccountButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnCreateAccount);
                mCreateAccountButton.setOnClickListener(this);
                return view;
        }
```

onsaveinstance code for login fragment

```
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {  
        outState.putString(EXTRA_USERNAME, mUserNameEditText.getText()
                .toString());
        outState.putString(EXTRA_PASSWORD, mPasswordEditText.getText()
                .toString());
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
onsaveinstance code for create account fragment
 @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

                if(savedInstanceState != null){
                        mEmailEditText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(EXTRA_EMAIL));
                        mUserNameEditText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(EXTRA_USERNAME));
                        mPasswordEditText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(EXTRA_PASSWORD));
                        mConfirmPasswordEditText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(EXTRA_CONFIRM));
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
                super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
                outState.putString(EXTRA_EMAIL, mEmailEditText.getText().toString());
                outState.putString(EXTRA_USERNAME, mUserNameEditText.getText().toString());
                outState.putString(EXTRA_PASSWORD, mPasswordEditText.getText().toString());
                outState.putString(EXTRA_CONFIRM, mConfirmPasswordEditText.getText().toString());
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activities are recreated on orientation change, effectively making it a new activity. [You need to override onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) and write the application state values you want to change to the Bundle parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android)

Comment: Did you implement the `onRestoreInstanceState` method too?

Comment: No. How do I do that?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.intertech.com/Blog/saving-and-retrieving-android-instance-state-part-2/